# How to get the Actual Path of a File in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the path of a database that I've made in an Android Studio project. It works fine when I hard code the path, but I'm unable to get the path otherwise. 
The actual path is:

> /data/data/package.name/databases/database.db

but functions like `getPath()` and `getDatabasePath()` return:

> data/user/0/package.name/databases/database.db

and I get:

> W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:

messages.
I guess that's the location of the Uri? How do I retrieve the actual path?

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing it the context? The code should look something like

```
String path = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
```

Where DATABASE_NAME is the name of your database, and your context should be a Context that you defined.

Comment: Yes, this is my exact code.         file = context.getDatabasePath("database.db");
        String outFileName =file.getAbsolutePath();

Answer (score -1):

> but functions like getPath() and getDatabasePath() return data/user/0/package.name/databases/database.db

What it returned is the correct answer, though you missed the leading slash.

> The actual path is /data/data/package.name/databases/database.db

Only on some OS versions, and sometimes only from outside the app itself. Android supports multiple users of a device; the path your app will see will depend on the user.

> and I get: W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:

That is a random warning, having nothing to do with this code.

> How do I retrieve the actual path?

Since that appears to be a path to a database, use `getDatabasePath()`.

Comment: I don't think I missed the leading slash. I'm printing the path to the console and it did not include it. It works when I hard code the /data/data path but not with data/user one.

Comment: @persiaprince: You might want to edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you are doing with this path and explaining what "works" means.

Comment: Sorry, turns out the slash was there. "Work" simply means that I'm able to access the database file.

Comment: @persiaprince: I don't know how you are trying to access it. Again, you might want to edit your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are you trying to use it and explain exactly what the symptoms are of the failure (e.g., post the Java stack trace of a crash).